# From file to dictionary object without loop

Tags: python

I want to read a text file and convert the content into dictionary. File content is as below:

```
a=15
b=22
c=31
d=42
```

Is there any python way to do it one for two line without using any loop?
Please help.

I tried the following:

```
x=open("file.txt").read()
z=dict(x.replace('\n',','))
```

But it is giving me an error.

Expected Result:

```
{'a': 15, 'b': 22, 'c': 31, 'd': 42}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One-liner with [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) object:

```
from csv import reader

d = {k: int(v) for k, v in reader(open(file), delimiter='=')}
print(d)
```

The output:

```
{'a': 15, 'b': 22, 'c': 31, 'd': 42}
```

---

If values don't have to be casted to `int` type (as shown in your question) - just use the following:

```
d = dict(reader(open(file), delimiter='='))
```

---

Another way could be using [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) routine (it would conveniently cast to `int` type):

```
import pandas as pd

d = dict(pd.read_csv(file, delimiter='=', header=None).to_records(index=False))
print(d)
```

The output:

```
{'a': 15, 'b': 22, 'c': 31, 'd': 42}
```

Comment: Thanks , this is a good answer, however I am looking for a way without using loop.

Comment: @KrishnaRao, but you need to cast your values to `int` type according to expected result

Comment: Why .do you want to not use loop? Is that a boundation from the user who is going to use the code?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest , I have already implemented a loop version. I am looking for a non-loop version. I can accept string type for value.

Comment: @KrishnaRao, use `dict(reader(open(file), delimiter='='))` in that case.

Comment: @KrishnaRao You may also check my answer for a different approach.

Comment: @KrishnaRao, you may also try using `pandas.read_csv` - it would conveniently cast to int type

Comment: Thank you @RomanPerekhrest , as of now I am using your first approach

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Can you please tell me how does this `reader(open(file), delimiter='=')` work behind the scenes ? Does it use any kind of **loop** or is it using something else to do this ?

Comment: @CodeIt, when you mentioning "behind the scenes" - the answer would be: ANY tool/stuff will iterate over lines in the given file (usually consuming it as iterator not as a list of lines) behind the scenes. As for `csv.reader` from documentation: *Return a reader object which will iterate over lines in the given csvfile. csvfile can be any object which supports the iterator protocol*

Answer (score 0):

Without any libraries

```
with open('input.txt', mode='r') as f:
    str = f.read()

z = dict(x.split('=') for x in str.split('\n'))
```

Edit without using loops:

```
with open('input.txt', mode='r') as f:
    str = f.read().replace('=', ' ').split()

z = dict(zip(str[::2], str[1::2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created code to convert it into `dict` without using any loops.

```
import json
lines = open("file.txt","r").read()
lines = "{\"" + lines.replace("\n",",\"").replace("=","\":") + "}" # create proper dictionary string. 
dict = json.loads(lines) # required to convert dictionary String to dictionary object
print(dict)
# outputs {'a': 15, 'b': 22, 'c': 31, 'd': 42}
```

> Note: *There exists multiple pythonic ways of doing it if that matters you amy check out @RomanPerekhrest's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57223815/3091398).*

Comment: I would recommend for you to add to your answer that this isn't a good approach (From Pythonic view), so newcomers would avoid this. But it's a very creative approach for educational purposes.

Comment: @AlexanderSantos I have added a note to my answer.

Comment: @CodeIt, If you are interested in unbiased review of your answer, I must say that 1) it'll read the whole file content into memory (assigning to identifier `lines`) 2) it welds an artificial json string with multiple replacements and should not be considered as robust solution. It shouldn't be used in production environment. (please don't use it in production)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I agree with you that it shouldn't be used in production environment. But i consider this as apt solution for OP since as per the question the objective is to get the dictionary without using any loops. Anyway i have also up-voted your solution finding it the *pythonic* way of achieving it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the entire file content as a string first, you can iterate through the file object and split the lines by `'-'` to pass to the `dict` constructor:

```
dict(line.split('=', 1) for line in open('file.txt'))
```